# Automatic filter parameter with WebApi in MVC6

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following this tutorial http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html and am wondering if it is possible for WebApi to provide generic filters. For example, that this would work: http://localhost:11979/api/todo?IsComplete=true without having to implement individual filters per model.

Any way for the framework to automatically recognize filter fields that exist within the model and query accordingly?